# Get all file names in directory using JFileChooser?

Tags: java, file, swing, list

I'm using this bit of code:

```
 fileBrowser() {
      String toReturn = null;
      JFileChooser Chooser = new JFileChooser();
      int choosen = Chooser.showOpenDialog(fileBrowser.this);
      if (choosen == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {         
            System.out.println(Chooser.getCurrentDirectory().toString()+"\\"+Chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
      }

  }
```

To get the selected file name and location, which is all working fine. I was wondering as an addition, is there also a way to get all the filenames in that directory as well?  something like `.getAllFiles()` I've had a search around and can't find one?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, use

```
File[] filesInDirectory = chooser.getCurrentDirectory().listFiles();
```

Then you can iterate over that array:

```
for ( File file : filesInDirectory ) {
    System.out.println(file.getName());
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use `list()`, since OP is only looking for file names?

Comment: Thanks, I've used list() and the above suggestion, exactly what I wanted, many thanks!

Comment: @Крысa: If that's *all* he wanted to do (and depending on his definition of "filename"), then yes.  But typically you actually want to interact with a `File` object at some point and I was trying to lead the OP away from using a String intermediary.  My preference is to stick with the real objects until it's time for presentation.  Also, if he did want to filter out directories that's much cleaner using a `FileFilter` than a `FilenameFilter`, and that is only available to `listFiles()`.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there's [`File.list()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29). This will list all files by their name from the specified directory (i.e. `File`). But this will also return directory names. In order to circumvent that, use the other [`File.list(FilenameFilter filter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29) method that will enable you to filter out directories from the listing.