# How to get next file from folder from JButton?

Tags: java, audio-player

I have a java program that plays audio file. 
Instead of having to use JFileChooser each time I want to play another audio file, I want to have a "next" button that will play the next audio file.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Select forlder with filechooser and get all audio file from there and put into list or array

Comment: @uzaif how do i get all the audio files and put it into an array?

Comment: for (File file : (List) FileUtils.listFiles(new File(srcDir), new String[] { "mp3","MP3"}, true)) { htmFileList.add(file); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load all files within the folder in a *JList*, storing in it's model the filename and filePath. You add to your JList an *ListSelectionListener*. Each time you push the "next" button change the current value in the JList with the next one. As a consequence an *Action* will be fired in JList. In the *ListSelectionListener* callback you play your "next audio file" using the same code as you play a single file, but with the new filename and filepath 
There are plenty of examples working with JList and JFileChooser. I mention only a few of them:

JFileChooser

[Get all file names in directory using JFileChooser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342849/get-all-file-names-in-directory-using-jfilechooser)
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/Getalistofselectedfiles.htm

JList

[Adding an ActionListener to a JList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609200/adding-an-actionlistener-to-a-jlist)

http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-jlist-listselectionlistener-event